# Сторонняя библиотека для смены кодировки строк в Android

Tags: java, android

Есть Android-приложение, которое общается с сервером. Сервер понимает строки в кодировке "CP866".
Привычная конструкция прекрасно работает:

`String string = new String(bytes, 0, bytes.length, "866");`

Однако не все устройства поддерживают данную кодировку. Как быть в этой ситуации? Есть ли сторонние библиотеки для кодирования строк?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен кастомный `CharsetProvider`, который поддерживает [866](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP866) кодировку

Вам нужно поискать провайдеров соответствующих *codepage*

Короткое гугление привело меня к [JCharset](https://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/) - не уверен поддерживает ли он 866, но ничто не мешает вам продолжить гугление.

Answer (score 0):

```
        static final int[] cp866={0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 1040, 1041, 1042, 1043, 1044, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1048, 1049, 1050, 1051, 1052, 1053, 1054, 1055, 1056, 1057, 1058, 1059, 1060, 1061, 1062, 1063, 1064, 1065, 1066, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1070, 1071, 1072, 1073, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1078, 1079, 1080, 1081, 1082, 1083, 1084, 1085, 1086, 1087, 9617, 9618, 9619, 9474, 9508, 9569, 9570, 9558, 9557, 9571, 9553, 9559, 9565, 9564, 9563, 9488, 9492, 9524, 9516, 9500, 9472, 9532, 9566, 9567, 9562, 9556, 9577, 9574, 9568, 9552, 9580, 9575, 9576, 9572, 9573, 9561, 9560, 9554, 9555, 9579, 9578, 9496, 9484, 9608, 9604, 9612, 9616, 9600, 1088, 1089, 1090, 1091, 1092, 1093, 1094, 1095, 1096, 1097, 1098, 1099, 1100, 1101, 1102, 1103, 1025, 1105, 1028, 1108, 1031, 1111, 1038, 1118, 176, 8729, 183, 8730, 8470, 164, 9632, 160};

        static String decode(String s){
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            int q=s.length();
            while(q>0){
                sb.insert(0,(char)cp866[s.codePointAt(--q)]);
            }
            return(sb.toString());
        }
```

Это же базовые вещи, любой программист должен уметь написать такое самостоятельно. А если не сможет - какой же он программист?

Comment: Должен уметь и должен писать это разные вещи.

Comment: А в чем тогда смысл существования программиста?